# UICollectionView - sections and rows based on CoreData on-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, uicollectionview

I have a datamodel that looks like this:

```
Location <------->> Item
```

Each location can have many items. I want to display these locations and items in a `UICollectionView`. Where I want each location to be a section that contains items. Like this:

```
-----------------------
I   Location 1        I
-----------------------
I Item 1   I  Item 2  I
I--------- I-----------
I   Location 2        I
-----------------------
        [...]
```

I wonder which way is the best to achieve this? I have never used sections before, so I'm not sure if that's the right way to go. And if it is the way to go, how do I get locations as sections and then display items inside those sections?

My current non working implemtation looks like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection: (NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Location" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext  sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

[...]

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Any ideas or recommendations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to fetch `Item` objects, and use the `sectionNameKeyPath:` parameter to group
the items into sections according to the related location:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

// The first sort descriptor must use the sectionNameKeyPath key:
NSSortDescriptor *sort1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"location.name" ascending:NO];
// The second sort descriptor sorts the items within each section:
NSSortDescriptor *sort2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sort1, sort2];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                      managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                        sectionNameKeyPath:@"location.name"
                                 cacheName:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. Do you also know how I could get a `Location` object from `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`?

Comment: @Anders: I would have to look it up, I don't know it by heart.

Comment: Ok, will create another question for it.

Comment: @Anders: It could be something similar to `id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][indexPath.section]; Item *item = sectionInfo.objects[0]; Location *location = item.location;` but this is not tested.

Comment: Mhm, I've tried something similar. The problem is that it's possible for each location to not have any items. So I keep getting `index 0 beyond bounds for empty array`.

Comment: I have asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607620/get-nsfetchedresultscontroller-section-object-from-uicollectionviews-viewforsup