# Get NSFetchedResultsController section object from UICollectionView's viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a data model called `Location`. I use these as my section headers in a `UICollectionViewController`. Each `location` can display `items` inside these sections. I want to customise my section headers in `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`. But I can't figure out how to recive the correct `Location` objects from this method.

I have tried things like:

```
-(UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView   viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections] [indexPath.section];
    Item *item = sectionInfo.objects[0];
    Location *location = item.location;   
    SectionHeaderView *headerView = [collectionView   dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader   withReuseIdentifier:@"SectionHeader" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    headerView.label.text = location.name;
    [...]
```

But I keep getting:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM   objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

This is probably because it's possible to have Location without any items. Any other ideas on how I should do it?

Comment: Does the problem occur only for sections without items? In other words, do you get the correct Location objects if all sections are non-empty?

Comment: No, but I'm not sure on how to get the correct locations if It doesn't have any items and I can't do `item.location`.

Comment: Actually I wonder how you get sections with zero items at all, when using the setup as in the answer to your previous question. There may be a problem in your data source or delegate methods. But I am not sure ...

Comment: @MartinR Yes, you're right. Tried again with a breakpoint and it crashes already on `id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][indexPath.section];`. Do you think I should use another approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks quite correct, and it worked as expected in my small test app.
Therefore I assume that you have some error in the data source methods.

This is what I used:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return [[self.frc sections] count];
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.frc sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CellView *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Item *item = [self.frc objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.name.text = item.name;
    return cell;
}

-(UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.frc sections][indexPath.section];
    Item *item = sectionInfo.objects[0];
    Location *location = item.location;
    HeaderView *headerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
                                                                withReuseIdentifier:@"HeaderView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    headerView.title.text = location.name;
    return headerView;
}
```

The fetched results controller is created as follows:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)frc
{
    if (_frc == nil ) {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Item"];
        NSSortDescriptor *sort1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"location.name" ascending:NO];
        NSSortDescriptor *sort2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sort1, sort2];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        _frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                   managedObjectContext:self.context
                                                     sectionNameKeyPath:@"location.name"
                                                              cacheName:nil];
        NSError *error;
        _frc.delegate = self;
        [_frc performFetch:&error];
    }
    return _frc;
}
```

*Remark:* The automatic *updates* of a collection view with a fetched results controller
are quite tricky, so this article

http://ashfurrow.com/blog/how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller-with-uicollectionview

(with code examples) might be interesting.

Comment: Thanks,  but this also means that each section / location must have at least one item? Looks very similar to what I have now. What do you think of: https://github.com/timothyarmes/TAFetchedResultsController ?

Comment: @Anders: My answer applies to the "normal" FRC, which (as far as I know) cannot have empty sections. I did not know that you use a "special" FRC. I will have a look at that project but probably not before tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, nice. I don't use it yet. But thinking of doing so. Let me know what you thinks! :)

Comment: @Anders: I am a little bit confused now about what your actual question is. If you use the "normal" FRC and not TAFetchedResultsController, then above code should work and not crash with an exception. At least it worked in a small test app that I created.

Comment: I think I found my problem. I had accidentially used `tableView numberOfSections` instead of `collectionView`. And I also decided to create a default item for each location so the sections always gets displayed.